# Selective stream.read()s vs one long stream.read()

Tags: c++, image, stream

I am building a composite image from thousands of individual frames that I register and then place. The individual frames are about 6400x4800 pixels, but ultimately only contribute about 200x500 pixels to the final composite image. I figure out what portions of the individual frames will make it to the composite image ahead of time by building a voronoi diagram/zbuffer of the composite image and then mapping the regions back to the contributing frames. I do this before I need to load the image data from disk. This creates a situation where I would like to read a small, noncontiguous piece of memory from disk. How do?

Is it faster to do something like this:

```
stream.open(image_file_path, std::ios::binary);
stream.read(raw_buffer, width*height);
stream.close();
```

or is it worth it to do this:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < region.height; i++){
   stream.seekg(read_location); 
   stream.read(&raw_buffer[i * region.width], region.width);
   read_location += width;
}
stream.close();
```

Comment: It’s always better not to read data you don’t need. Your first might or might not be quicker No but the second will use less memory.

Comment: Alternatively, memory map the files (with an `madvise` that you're going to be doing mostly random access) and just copy over the regions you need? It will be a hell of a lot quicker to code.

Comment: IMHO, a better method is to use *double buffering* or *multiple buffering* and at least two threads.  One thread starts reading into a buffer.  When buffer is full, the next buffer is read into and the reader thread notifies the main thread that the buffer is ready to process.  Remember, reading from a file is much slower than reading from memory.  Also, the best efficiency you can achieve is to keep the stream flowing.

Comment: I'm not sure you have a problem at all.  The amount of data you're reading is small, for modern hardware, especially if you have an SSD.